«Три сестры красавицы» — знаки
Белая лебедушка. Русские волшебные сказки (Марья Моревна; обработка И. Карнауховой):

В некотором царстве, в некотором государстве жил-был богатырь Фёдор
Тугарин; были у него три сестры красавицы: Марья-девица,
Ольга-девица и Анна-девица.

Чем объясняется непостановка дефиса или тире между словами сестры и красавицы?
Слово красавицы может быть:
а) приложением к слову сестры — тогда ставим дефис: три сестры-красавицы;
б) приложением к сочетанию три сестры — тогда ставим тире (ПАС, § 154, п. 1): три сестры — красавицы.
(Второй вариант как будто вносит двусмысленность: красавицы могут быть восприняты как именная часть сказуемого: были у него три сестры — красавицы.)

Не знаю, почему нет никакого знака, я бы поставил запятую, отделяя приложение.
...были у него три сестры, красавицы: Марья-девица, Ольга-девица и Анна-девица.
Числительное ставит определяемое слово в родительный падеж единственного числа: три сестры, поэтому дефис не подойдёт, он был бы уместен в сочетании сёстры-красавицы.
Тире, на мой взгляд, не вносит двусмысленность, так как при таком порядке слов и при первом упоминании о сёстрах слово красавицы не может являться частью сказуемого. Но тире тоже не лучший вариант (или даже ошибочный). Просто это довольно сильный знак, и с помощью него выделяются приложения, имеющие, например, пояснительный характер (см. пункт 10 по ссылке). Да и ещё одна заметная пауза в данном предложении ни к чему.
Остаётся запятая.
Пример из правил:
Ухаживала за мной одна девушка, полька.
Обособленные приложения (справочник Розенталя)
P. S. Сказки – особый жанр... И на то они и сказки, чтобы иметь свой, волшебный стиль изложения. А от этого и структура словосочетаний может не подчиняться привычным законам. Возникло предположение, что "три сестры красавицы" здесь  является единым целым, ведь если переставить слова и написать "три красавицы сестры", то знака не будет.

Приветствую тебя, Саша! Давненько не пересекались... Сплю уже ж почти... завтра гляну... (У тебя всегда все гладко. Завидую...)

Спасибо, Римма! Привет-привет! На этот раз, да и не только на этот, может быть и не гладко :) Есть предположение, что это особый сказочный стиль, где свои законы изложения и пунктуации, а всё сочетание "три сестры красавицы" считается единым целым... И прочитать его можно слитно. Пожалуй, добавлю это в постскриптум.


Это песня (встречаются два варианта):

Три сестры-красавицы, надо ж им понравиться.
Три сестры красавицы, надо ж им понравиться.

А это как бы стих:

Три красавицы сестры, Будьте вы всегда добры! Все по правилам.

А это сказка, где ни одного дефиса (ни к чему они в сказках):

В некотором царстве, в некотором государстве жил был богатырь Фёдор Тугарин, были у него три сестры красавицы: Марья девица, Ольга девица и Анна девица.
Так себе богатырь...  Ни одного богатырского подвига.

А это решение задачи (решить можно всё)

Рассмотрим сочетание: красавица (красивая) сестра. Это сочетание приложение + определение По Розенталю при определительном значение приложения знака нет.  Но сестра-красавица. Классика!
Рассмотрим сочетание сестра красавица. Это тоже приложение + определение, только теперь определяемым (главным) словом будет красавица, а сестра – приложением.
Почему бы и нет? Пусть это будет существительное, которое несет основную семантическую и эмоциональную нагрузку: были у него три сестры красАвицы.
Ударная позиция в сказочном тексте. Были бы не красавицы, то откуда женихам таким завидным взяться: Сокол, Орел и Ворон. Они и спасали богатыря Федора, когда он со Змеем Горынычем сражался, а тот его на мелкие кусочки изрубил.
Вариант с перестановкой приложения и определяемого слова вполне возможен, что видно на примере француз-гувернер и гувернер-француз, когда определяемым может быть любое существительное в зависимости от текста. Ну а в сказке тем более чудеса возможны.
Но в действительности дело в том, что сказочный текст особенный, напевный, поэтому для него нехарактерно дефисное написание слов.

Поздравляю всех с наступающим Новым годом! Побольше  сказочных и добрых сюжетов в вашей жизни.

И вам, и вам всего хорошего, Sharon! Спасибо!!!

А дефис ни при каких раскладах не вписывается. Из-за числительного. Он может появиться, только если оба слова будут в одном падеже, когда речь об одной персонажке –
сестре-красавице. Сестры-красавицы – родительный падеж единственного числа.

Почему не вписывается, дефис возможен. Здесь числительное три сочетается с существительным в форме ед. числа Р. п.  Тогда:  сестра-красавица, нет сестры-красавицы, три сестры-красавицы.

Второй ответ

Дефисное написание возможно: три сестры-красавицы.

Здесь числительное три сочетается с существительным в форме ед. числа Р. п. Тогда: сестра-красавица, нет сестры-красавицы, три сестры-красавицы. Красавица как приложение к обороту три сестры.

Правило ПАС с постановкой тире нельзя применять, так это правило не подходит для числового оборота, который считается неразложимым сочетанием и может рассматриваться как одно слово.

Но в АГ-80 есть примеры на правило с тире: Владимир — Красное Солнышко, Ивашка —  белая рубашка. Из сказок подходит Иван —  крестьянский сын.

В сказочном тексте нет дефиса, так как сочетание сестра красавица может трактоваться достаточно свободно. Можно считать, что три сестры —  это приложение в препозиции к сущ. красавицы.

ПРАВИЛО
§ 154. В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире. 1. В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей содержит пробел.
   Примеры с неоднословными определяемыми: встреча с гостями 
   Олимпиады — иностранцами, старшего лейтенанта — 
   артиллериста, участников войны — инвалидов, о Михаиле 
   Булгакове — актёре и т. д.
   Примеры с неоднословными приложениями: творчество поэтов 
   — современников Пушкина; статьи о Горьком — общественном 
   деятеле, о Маршаке — переводчике Шекспира и т.д.

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (текстовый пример)
 Закручинилась Баба Яга: всё из избушки пропало! Три 
 скатерти-самобранки, три цветика-семицветика, три шапки- 
 невидимки.  Запечалился Кощей Бессмертный, куда что 
 девалось?  Три меча-кладенца, трое сапог-скороходов, три 
 Жар-птицы в клетках золоченых.
 Не иначе как **Иван — крестьянский сын** у них побывал и 
 подарки к Новому году украл! Это у него **три сестры 
 красавицы** да два брата молодца-удальца… 

Мораль. Смотреть надо лучше за вещами)


